# How can I check /dev/xvda1?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, fsck

On login to EC2 (Ubuntu) instance, I see

```
*** /dev/xvda1 should be checked for errors ***
```

I can't `fsck /dev/xvda1` because it is mounted, and `sudo umount /dev/xvda1` fails because it is in use.  `lsof` shows

```
jbd2/xvda  172               root  cwd       DIR              202,1     4096          2 /
jbd2/xvda  172               root  rtd       DIR              202,1     4096          2 /
jbd2/xvda  172               root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/172/exe
```

and `kill -SIGKILL 172` is ineffective.

What to do?

Comment: Can you set /dev/xvda1 to "noauto" in fstab and reboot?

Comment: For Ubuntu, see the answer at http://askubuntu.com/a/548772/184435

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Most Linuxes these days should perform a forced fsck at boot time when the file /forcefsck is present on the system. 
If you are at liberty to reboot the VM,  run

```
touch /forcefsck
```

Then reboot at your convenience

Answer (score 104):

For our ec2 ubuntu instance, the above answers did not work completely.

On Ubuntu, by default, the check is not enabled in the [rcS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/rcS.5.html) file. So

1. Edit rcS file
   `sudo vi /etc/default/rcS`

below the line

```
#FSCKFIX=no
```

Add

```
FSCKFIX=yes
```

2. Edit fstab file: `sudo vi /etc/fstab`

Look for the the record for / and if the last digit is `0` change it to `1`. The last field is fsckorder and is used by fsck to decide the order of checking disks. [If the value is `0` that disk is skipped](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/fstab.htm).

For e.g.,

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
```

to

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 1
```

3. Create /forcefsck file: `sudo touch /forcefsck`

Reboot from ec2 console.

Revert the fsckorder value from `1` to `0` in /etc/fstab
Delete the line `FSCKFIX=yes` to get back rcS file to original state.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Simply doing "touch /forcefsck" doesn't solve it, I had to enable FSCKFIX also.

Comment: Same here; just doing `sudo touch /forcefsck` before rebooting did not work on an Ubuntu 14.04 system, but this answer did.

Comment: I had to do one other step - a modification to /etc/fstab as described here: https://nathanpfry.com/fix-dev-xvda1-should-be-checked-for-errors-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-instances/  That's odd because the last time I had this happen, I used your answer and it worked as is.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved it for me on an ec2 instance from AWS. I didn't have to reboot from the console, a simple `sudo reboot` with your changes resolved this.

Comment: This also fixed the issue on my local computer. I believe this should be marked as best.

Comment: @childofsoong The article you linked to doesn't suggest anything different from this answer. Again, the steps above worked for me on an EC2 instance, however rebooting from the console didn't do it, I had to `sudo reboot`.

Comment: @n3rve that was added after my comment (see the revision history). As for rebooting from ec2 console vs on instance, I can't comment - I probably just did it on instance myself, because it's faster when I'm already logged in.

Comment: FYI: This worked - but had to do it for both `/` and `/boot` - and you can do both at the same time (i.e. set the `/etc/fstab` for both `/` and `/boot` to `1`) - to save yourself a reboot.

Answer (score 7):

Since you cannot boot into live disc, this is may sounds a bit weird, but i guess it'll do the job)

high level:

- boot into new (another) instance.
- attach storage from old instance to new (current).
- run `fsck`.
- detach storage from new (current) and reattach it to old instance.

Answer (score 1):

I just do 3 steps below and issue resolved.

1. Add "FSCKFIX=yes" to /etc/default/rcS
2. sudo touch /forcefsck
3. sudo reboot

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three steps:

1. Edit `rcS` file
   `sudo vi /etc/default/rcS`

below the line

```
# FSCKFIX=no
```

Add `FSCKFIX=yes`

2. Then do this:

`sudo touch /forcefsck`

3. Reboot from EC2 console.

You can login back and check it has gone away

[Original answer here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/dev-xvda1-should-be-checked-for-errors-4175539261/)