# How can I check /dev/xvda1 if the command 'touch /forcefsck' doesn't work?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, fsck

On login to EC2 (Ubuntu) instance, I see

```
*** /dev/xvda1 should be checked for errors ***
```

I can't `fsck /dev/xvda1` because it is mounted, and `sudo umount /dev/xvda1` fails because it is in use.
So I tried to use `sudo touch /forcefsck` as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/627371/how-can-i-check-dev-xvda1) but it doesn't work, when I did it nothing happened on terminal.  What to do?

Comment: Did you actually reboot the instance after performing the `touch` command? The command by itself just makes a file, but you have to reboot the server for the actual check to take place.

Comment: @WildVelociraptor I had reboot the instance but nothing happened...I don't know why, but after few hours without did anything, the message is not more displayed

Comment: If it says that it should be checked for errors, there may be actual errors on it. Make (have) backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as alternative to `touch /forcefsck`, one can attach dirty volume to another instance, run `fsck` on that dirty volume and reattach it back to original instance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply edit the file /etc/default/rcS

Uncomment and set FSCKFIX=yes

```
/etc/default/rcS
# automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot
FSCKFIX=yes
```

and reboot!

Do remember to put it back afterwards.